# Select a datetime data set by day plus one in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am working on a C# program where I have to select some specific datetime records from 2012 SQL server.
The data record has two DateTime columns, start and ending. I just need the data if begin and ending is not the same day.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(start AS DATE) != CAST(end AS DATE)
```

but this is not the problem yet. I need it a little bit more specific, I only want the data if the end date is the starting date plus one day, no matter what time booth of them have.

I made some pseudocode, unfortunately my SQL skills are quite limited.

```
 SELECT Convert(date, getdate()) start
 FROM table
 WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT Convert(date, getdate())Ende FROM table  WHERE end = dateadd(day,1,start) )
```

The result should be all rows where start + 1 day = end (ignoring the time in the DateTime), so I can work with the data in my c# Programm.

I hope you can help me out, thank you.

Comment: `CAST(start AS DATE) = CAST(dateadd(dd,-1,end) AS DATE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, [start], [end]) = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387208)**</kbd>

Comment: Worked perfect for me, thank you! Good to know that there is such a function.